# Second variation of a Brownian motion under jump-diffusion process

Tags: brownian-motion, jump-diffusion, poisson-process

I am trying to solve exercise 15.3 from the book *The concepts and practice of mathematical finance* where it is asked

> Suppose the $\log S_t$ follows a Brownian motion over the period $[0, 1]$ except at time $0.5$ where it jumps by $x$. What are the first and second variations of $\log S_t$ over the period $[0, 1]$.

The first variation is easily determined to be $\infty$, as in a continuous Brownian motion.

A continuous Brownian motion should also have its second variation equal to $T$, so here - not considering the jump - it would be equal to $T = 1$. But unlike the first variation, the second one is a finite value, so should be susceptible to the presence of the jump.

Indeed the solution reported in the book states the second variation to be equal to $1.25$.

Where does this result comes from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ X_t = B_t 1_{t<0.5} + (x+ B_t) 1_{t\geq 0.5} =  B_t + x1_{t\geq 0.5}$$

$$ [X, X]_t = [B, B]_t + x^2 1_{t\geq 0.5} = t+ x^2 1_{t\geq 0.5}$$

(the author probably intended to use $0.5$ as jump size too)

Comment: Nice. The double product $B_t x$ in the last expression is tossed out because the mean of $B_t$ is assumed $= 0$, am I right?

Comment: @Giogre it’s because the quadratic variation, that is $[\cdot,\cdot]_t$, between a Brownian Motion and a jump process is null.

Comment: Yes, $B_t$ is a continous process while $Y_t = x1_{t\leq 0.5}$ is a finite variation process, so their quadratic covariation is $0$. See Lemma 3 [here](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/01/19/properties-of-quadratic-variations/).

Comment: I see the link provided. I imagined the *Concepts* book was self-contained, not requiring more stochastic calculus than that already in the book. Basically $x 1_{t \geq 0.5}$ is a step function hence its variation should be zero. Is this a good intuitive explanation? Then why should the quadratic covariation be $0$ only if the other process is continuous? What changes if it were another step function, for instance?

Comment: I included an elementary proof of that fact starting from the quadratic covariation definition [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/63229/6858) on the Stack.

Comment: Ok, there you show that the variation of a continuous process $B_t$ has $0$ as an upper bound because all increments of a continuous function have $\lim_{\Delta \to 0} = 0$ and null is also their sum. I understand, there is no intuitive explanation.

Comment: The first variation of $B_t$ is infinite, not $0$. The first variation of $Y_t$ is bounded by say $V$. It is the *continuity* of $B_t$ (equation (1) in the link) that makes the limit needed for calculating the quadratic covariation equal to  $0$ times $V$. In other words, *continuity* of $B_t$ *kills* the *finite* jumps in the covariation calculation.

Comment: The max interval $ | B_{t_{j+1}} - B_{t_j} | $ has upper bound $0$ due to the continuity of $B_t$, not the variation of $B_t$ as I stated before, my bad.